# CSS selector not able to recognize full name of div - class name it takes only first 3 words

Tags: html, css, frontend

Learning CSS and creating 3 div where I give all 3 dive classes as TopContainer, MiddleContainer, BottomContainer.
Now while styling it in external css choosing as . Top I able to style
but using its real name which is TopContainer it's not working.

```
</div>
<div class="MiddleContainer"></div>
<div class="BottomContainer"></div>
```

Created div give them name as above says while styling is working only as on external css which shown below which is super awkward Please someone can explain me this.

```
.Top{ 
margin: 0px; 
background-color: #e4f9f5; 
    }

.Middle{ 
height: 200px; 
width: 200px; 
background-color: red; 
    }

.Bottom{ 
height: 200px; 
width: 200px;
text background-color: blue;    
    }
```

Comment: you don't have class Middle but MiddleContainer. Same for Bottom <-> BottomContainer

Answer (score 1):

you don't have exact match between class name in the HTML and CSS

when changed CSS classes to `TopContainer`, `MiddleContainer`, `BottomContainer`

it works see snippet bellow

```css
.TopContainer { 
  margin: 0px; 
  background-color: #e4f9f5; 
}

.MiddleContainer { 
  height: 200px; 
  width: 200px; 
  background-color: red; 
}

.BottomContainer { 
  height: 200px; 
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;    
}
```

```html
<div class="TopContainer">Top</div>
<div class="MiddleContainer">Middle</div>
<div class="BottomContainer">Bottom</div>
```